# Why NoMethodError for instance method of another class in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a Player class in player.rb

```
class Player
  attr_reader :name, :symbol
  ...
  def make_move?(position, board)
    if board.move_valid?(position)
        board.update(position, symbol)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
  end 
  ...
end
```

The `board.move_valid?` and other board methods are defined in the file for the `Board` class, `board.rb`

```
class Board
...
  def move_valid?(position)
    correct_pos = ("1".."9").include?(move)
    if correct_pos
      is_not_occupied = pos[move.to_i - 1].eql?(move)
    end
    correct_pos and is_not_occupied
  end

  def update(p, s)
  ...
  end
...
end
```

Both class files are in the `lib` folder.

On running `rspec` command from the project's root directory, I get the **error**:

```
Player
  #make_move?
    marks a valid spot on the board (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Player#make_move? marks a valid spot on the board
     Failure/Error: if board.move_valid?(position)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `move_valid?' for "3":String
     # ./lib/player.rb:12:in `make_move?'
     # ./spec/player_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.0032 seconds (files took 0.11769 seconds to load)
16 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/player_spec.rb:6 # Player#make_move? marks a valid spot on the board
```

The corresponding rspec test file contents are:

```
require './lib/player'
require './lib/board'

describe Player do
    describe "#make_move?" do
        it "marks a valid spot on the board" do
            player = Player.new("Abc", "X")
            board = Board.new
            expect(player.make_move?(board, "3")).to eql(true)
        end
    end
end
```

The project involves a `main.rb` file in a `bin` folder which `require`s both the class definitions, and works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `def board.update(p, s)` crashes at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is occuring because of the order of the variables you are passing into `make_move`.

`make_move` takes in `position` followed by `board`.  The error is stating that `move_valid` is is a string instead of an instance of `Board`.

This line should have the parameters swapped as shown:

```
expect(player.make_move?("3", board)).to eql(true)
```

Comment: Oops!! I was racking my head against it for some time now. Thanks.